# Ambiguity of 'Blank Paper', 'Blank Lined Paper', and 'Lined Paper which is not blank'

Tags: ambiguity

This happened with me. I asked my daughter to get me a blank paper and she gave me this.

[image]

When I asked this is not the blank paper, she said it is, there's nothing written on this.

Whereas I was asking for this -

[image]

If I say give me **a lined paper**, this is also a lined paper but it's **not blank**.

[image]

If I say give me a **lined blank paper**, how is it blank? It has lines on it! :)

Comment: NOAD says: **blank** (*adj.*) not written or printed on. Your daughter was correct :^) She may not have given you what you wanted, but she gave you what you asked for.

Comment: That ballpoint is *not* ubiquitous. I can never find it when I want it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is **plain paper**. This means unlined paper. (It may or may not be blank.)

From the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/plain_1?q=+plain+paper):

> **plain paper**
>   › paper that has no lines on it: *a letter written on plain paper*

---

As for blank paper, the [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blank) lists blank as:

> **1.a.** Devoid of writing, images, or marks: *a blank page; a blank screen.*

which could imply (I'm not convinced it is 100% clear, but you could make the case for it) that lined paper that has not been written on is not blank, because of the lines.

However, from experience as a native speaker, **I have found "blank paper" to be ambiguous**: in practice, some people use it to mean *completely blank* and others use it to mean *not yet written on*.

For that reason, I would suggest using *plain paper* for a completely empty sheet and perhaps *blank lined paper* or *unused lined paper* to indicate that you want paper that has lines but hasn't been used. (Or you could just say *lined paper* - people will probably assume you want a clean sheet of it.)

Comment: @maulikv: As a boy in school (in, say, 1967--some things appear not to change quickly), my teachers constantly asked us to "take out a blank sheet of paper."  This would be exactly the sort of paper that your daughter gave you.  It may be ambiguous to a native speaker, but not to an American schoolteacher!

Comment: @Bob I should clarify - it's often clearer in context (presumably you often/always used lined paper at school). In an art lesson, a "blank sheet of paper" could mean a plain sheet ;)

Comment: I have to say I'd tend to assume "blank" meant "unwritten on" rather than "plain and unwritten on", but I couldn't find any dictionaries that made it clear - if anything they tended to lean the other way.

Comment: @starsplusplus yes, absolutely. I didn't mean to attempt to refute what you said. Art paper is a great example of blank meaning devoid of markings.  I was rather pointing out what Maulik's daughter's experience is likely to be.

Comment: Plain paper with lines on it!!